# iOS: how to scale up image nicely?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cifilter

I'm having trouble scaling up an image in a nice way. I'm displaying an image in a UIImageView. But while the image is downloading from the server, I'd like to display a blurred version of the image. The server quickly gives me a small version of the image that looks like this:

[image: small preview image]

Magnified, it looks like this:

[image: large preview image]

I'd like to be able to draw it like this (which is how Chrome draws it when I scale the image up):

[image: chrome blurred image]

But when I put the image into a UIImageView and set imageview.layer.magnificationFilter to kCAFilterLinear or kCAFilterTrilinear, I get this:

[image: uiimageview scaled image]

... which is ugly - notice the hard bands of light and dark.

I've tried using CIFilter with CILanczosScaleTransform, and that looks promising, but I get an ugly border effect:

[image: lanczos scaled image]

Well - any advice? Anybody done this nicely? I can try filters forever, thought I'd see if anybody's cracked this...

EDIT: I tried bbarnhart's suggestion. I get this - nicer, but the blur radius is too large or something:

[image: visual effect blur]

EDIT 2: @bbarnhart, I can now get this, much closer!

[image]

Comment: The question seems to depend entirely upon your personal aesthetics for what is acceptable. That is not a programming matter, and in any case no one can read your mind. Only _you_ can know what you want and decide whether a given implementation gives an okay rendering, so you just have to keep trying stuff.

Comment: @matt: incorrect. I stated what I want to achieve: the second image, and what I've tried, and am asking for programming solutions to get there. This is entirely a programming question.

Comment: But then, in effect, you are just asking "how does Chrome achieve this effect"? But none of us knows _that_, and iOS is not Chrome.

Comment: I used the first very blocky image in the playground instead of the ones from the magnificationFilter.  It looked very close to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @matt: also incorrect: I don't care how chrome does it, just how can I achieve it in iOS.

Comment: @bbarnhart nice, I tried that, it's closer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the blur effect on your UIImageView might give you something closer to what you want.

```
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))    
blurView.frame = yourImageView.bounds
yourImageView.addSubview(blurView)
```

Also check out [bluuur](https://github.com/ML-Works/Bluuur)

Update to include a playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let image = UIImage(named: "pixels")
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 346, height: 431))
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
blurView.frame = imageView.bounds
imageView.addSubview(blurView)

view.addSubview(imageView)
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

Comment: thanks, that's interesting, and it does look better, but not ideal (see results above)